# How do I make a search bar look for the information typed and find it in the api with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api

I want to make a page that finds github users "https://api.github.com/users".
But I don't know how to make the search bar look for the user within the API.
https://github.com/douglasbarreiros701/Pesquisar-usuarios-do-GitHub/blob/main/README.md

Picture of how it's getting

[image: 1]

```
    function GetUser(){
fetch("https://api.github.com/users")
.then(snapshot =>{
    console.log(snapshot)
})
}
GetUser()
```

Comment: Please add more information, like the code you have now, what the search bar actually needs to search, ...

Comment: Ok I put my project on github. The link is up there.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look in the code and post you an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: man I haven't put it yet so javaScript knows what I'm typing but I know how to do it... The only thing I don't know how to do is for example
Hey I typed "douglasbarreiros701" and the api gives me the information of that user that I typed in the search bar

Comment: thank you very much if you can help me i already looked for the content all over the internet and i didn't find how to do that

Comment: I opened a PR on GitHub. Please merge to get the code.

Comment: I already merged the code.  Can you check to see if you're right buddy?

Comment: bro thank you very much my dear I'm going to study everything you put there I can't believe it's working. Seriously thank you so much you have no idea how happy I am.